# Can you prove that phrase "it's important that you to remove" is grammatically incorrect?

Tags: grammar, infinitives, that

I found several times in books the structure with that-clause, where they put the infinitive with the particle "to" after "that".

For example, from *Advanced Apple Debugging & Reverse Engineering* by Derek Selandar (emphasis mine):

> Since this book involves debugging not only your own applications, but any application you’re curious about, **it’s important that you to remove** this feature while you learn about debugging so you can inspect any application of your choosing.

I think it's incorrect. How can I prove it?

Comment: It sounds wrong to me. Can you provide some examples?

Comment: This is an example from the book by Derek Selander, Advanced Apple Debugging & Reverse Engineering, Razeware LLC 2017.
Here is the full sentence: "Since this book involves debugging not only your own applications, but any application you’re curious about, it’s important that you to remove this feature while you learn about debugging so you can inspect any application of your choosing."

Comment: It looks to me as though the author hesitated between _important for you to remove_ and _important that you remove_ , and accidentally left in the _to_.

Comment: I'm not sure how to actually prove that something is ungrammatical. At best, you can only point to examples of constructions that are considered grammatical, but which don't include the construction in question. After a certain point, acceptable grammar can only be substantiated through common consensus. This reminds me of the fallacy that if somebody can't provide definitive proof of the *nonexistence* of something, then that's evidence that it must exist …

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, the construction in the question is ungrammatical. I'm also quite sure that the majority of people would hold the same opinion. Two examples of a grammatical version of the phrase are given in a previous comment.

Comment: I'd imagine the author themself would back @Kate up. It's ungrammatical. Two grammatical variants in mind, incorrectly mixing them in getting the thought down.

Comment: I can provide you with more examples: - **It’s important that you to double check** the accuracy of your cattle applications to avoid requesting any amendments at a later date.
- **It’s important that you to feel** comfortable with us and we want you to have a fun day filled with what is important to you.
- **It’s important that you to stick** to the bitrate limits listed above when streaming.
- **It’s important that you to know** which session your courses are housed under. (https://www.uccs.edu/registrar/short-course-deadlines/understanding-course-session-deadlines)

Comment: Google finds a total of ***six*** examples for "it's important that you to," one of which is this page. Compare this with the number of examples they claim they find for "it's important for you to" and "it's important that you." I consider this ***clear*** evidence that's it's grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Ever written or contributed to a book? The typos hit you in the eye when you pick up the printed copy, despite all the work you put into proof reading. Get real.

Comment: The examples provided by @diriger are virtually all sentences that sound like they’re written by non-native speakers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply bad syntax.  Any way you analyze it, "it’s important that you to remove this feature" doesn't parse.  "That you" is expecting a "normal" verb, and an infinitive verb [cannot function as a normal verb](https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/parts-of-speech/verbs/infinitive-verb.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to prove it's incorrect I think by referring to the present subjunctive mood.

The word "remove" here is not an infinitive. It is in the subjunctive mood, which in this case looks like the basic form of the verb. However, if you changed the person into the 3rd one, the form of the verb wouldn't change: **it is important that he remove**.

It is a typical form if it is preceded by a clause expressing obligation, necessity.

It is formal, probably more common in AmE.

The subordinate clauses can take other - regular - forms but not a full infinitive. So also possible are:

**It is important that he should remove**... and

**It is important that he removes**...

https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/the-subjunctive